# Multiple forms on one PHP page error handling (javascript )

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Hello I have these two forms in one PHP page ...
The registration form was working fine , java script function was called correctly and posting variables and inserting to db was fine.
The contact form was sending emails too with no errors.
Now i put them in the same PHP page and I had errors.
Send submit button in contact us is calling js function  !
I tried create forms with action="" and test the action value like one mentioned but don't know how to post the variables

```
<?php
  $action1=$_POST['action1'];
  if($action1=="1")
    header("Location:RegistrationAction.php");
  else if($action1=="2")
   header("Location:contactusAction.php");
?>
```

Form 1

```
<form method="post"  id ="reg_form" name="signup" action="Registrationaction.php"onsubmit="return submitform()" >

<input type="hidden" id="action1_1"name="action1" value="1"/>

<h4 id="req">*Donates Required Fields</h4>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>title</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="title"/></td>
   <td><label style="color:red; display:none;" id="title_error">Enter Your Title</label>
   </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>First name*</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="fname"/></td>
  <td><label style="color:red; display:none;" id="fname_error">Enter Your First      name</label>
  </td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="reg" id="sub1" value="Register"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Form 2

```
<form id="contactus" name="contact_form" action="contactusAction.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="action1_2"name="action1" value="2"/>
 <label for='name' >Full name </label><br/>
 <input type='text' name='full_name' id='name'  maxlength="50" /><br/>

 <label for='email' >Email Address</label><br/>
 <input type='text' name='contact_email' id='contact_email' maxlength="50" /><br/>

 <label for='message' >Message</label><br/>
 <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'> </textarea>

  <input type='submit' name='Send' id="sub2" value="Send" />

</form>
```

Comment: what JavaScript? Welcome to SO. Please have a look at the [help]

Comment: javascript tests if there are empty fields in registration form !

Comment: How to help without seeing the code that may give errors? Also are there any messages in the console?

Comment: i sumbit the contact form so it take registeraction instead of contactaction